# how to import angularjs module which has hyphens in its name in ES6

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, import

I am trying to use this [**md-steppers**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-steppers) npm package in my angularjs app with webpack and having a hard time. This is also happening with [**angular-cache-buster**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cache-buster) npm package

So, I installed it via npm and used the following import statement

```
import mdSteppers from 'md-steppers';
```

and added it in the angularjs DI as below

```
angular.module('myapp', [ mdSteppers ]
```

I am getting the error shown below

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module bolt due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=module&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/angular/angular.js?:68:12)
    at assertArg (webpack:///./node_modules/angular/angular.js?:1880:11)
    at assertArgFn (webpack:///./node_modules/angular/angular.js?:1890:3)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/angular/angular.js?:4573:11)
    at forEach (webpack:///./node_modules/angular/angular.js?:322:20)
    at loadModules (webpack:///./node_modules/angular/angular.js?:4548:5)....
```

I checked the module name for this npm package and it looks like below

```
angular.module('md-steppers', [
  'material.core',
  'material.components.icon']);

/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name mdStep
 * @module md-steppers
 *
 * @restrict E
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import {name as mdStepper} from 'md-steppers';
angular.module('myapp', [mdSteppers]);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I still see the above error I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

There is no any exported modules in this package.
So, you can use it only this way:

```
import angular from 'angular';    
import mdStepper from 'md-steppers';

angular.module('myapp', ['md-steppers']);
```

Comment: it does not throw any error but also it is not allowing to have strings in angular DI. My code editor also shows the import statement as unused because I am not using **mdStepper** in your import statement.

Comment: It allows only array of strings. You can see it here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module - `!Array.<string>=`

Comment: Yes, the mdStepper doesn't used but import is required for its register. You can write `import 'md-steppers';`